# Issue with installing CPAN XML::RSS

Tags: debian, perl

I'am running debian on my server and want to install the CPAN module `XML::RSS`. 
But I get this error:

http://pastebin.com/5syPaQfe (Pastebin because it's really long)

I'am trying to install [RequestTracker](http://bestpractical.com/rt/) and installed the dependancies with `make fixdeps`. The only dep missing is `XML::RSS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just install using package management? XML::RSS Perl module is available in the package [`libxml-rss-perl`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libxml-rss-perl).

```
$ apt-get install libxml-rss-perl
```

And it will resolve all dependencies for you. :)

For others you might need, just search your package manager:

```
$ apt-cache search XML::RSS
```